# Handling different argument types in subclasses with a single base class interface

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a factory that let's you create some Things of varying type. The values of each thing come from differing sources and are of differing types.
I want the class consumer to use a single getValue() and setValue() interface in order to do some important work in the base class. I also want the subclasses
to be able to handle a few different argument types. Currently, I am doing some type identification jiggery-pokery (see Thing2) to handle different types. Is there a better way to do this?

My question: Am I doing the right thing here?

```
abstract class Thing {

    public static Thing thingFactoryCreationary(byte iClass) {
        // let's assume this is more sophisticated in real life.
        return iClass==1 ? new Thing1() : new Thing2();
    }

    final public Object getValue() {
        myImportantWorkFunction();
        return _getValue();
    }

    final public void setValue(Object oValue) {
        myImportantWorkFunction();
        _setValue(oValue);
    }

    private void myImportantWorkFunction() {
        // save the world here.
    }        

    abstract protected Object _getValue();
    abstract protected void _setValue(Object oValue);
}

class Thing1 extends Thing {
    private String msMyStringPropertyValue;
    protected String _getValue() {
        return msMyStringPropertyValue;
    }
    protected void _setValue(Object oValue) {
        msMyStringPropertyValue = oValue.toString();
    }
}

class Thing2 extends Thing {

    protected InputStream _getValue() {
        return new FileInputStream("/some/file/descriptor");
    }

    protected void _setValue(Object oValue) {
        InputStream oInStream = null;            
        if (InputStream.class.isInstance(oValue)) {
            oInStream =(InputStream)oValue;
        } else {
            if (File.class.isInstance(oValue)) {
                oInStream = new FileInputStream((File)oValue);
            } else {
                oInStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(oValue.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));                
            }                                       
        }
        FileOutputStream oOutStream = new FileOutputStream("/some/file/descriptor");
        myFileStreamCopyFunction(oInStream, oOutStream);
    }

    private void myFileStreamCopyFunction(InputStream oInStream, OutputStream oOutStream) {
        // reading and writing is fundamental.
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a fine way. Perhaps you can specify with generics the accepted type:

```
public abstract class Thing<S, G> {
    private G value;
    public void setValue(S object);
    public G getValue();
}
public class Thing1 extends Thing<String, String> {..}
public class Thing2 extends Thing<ResourceHolder, String> {..}
```

Where `ResourceHolder` is a simple bean with getters and setters for `InputStream` and `File`. `S` and `G` stand for setter and getter - you specify what you expect to set, and what the client expects when he calls `get`

So each subclass can handle exactly one type of value, but that type can hold multiple options in it. That way, instead of reflection, you'd use a simple `null` check.

Comment: I do like like the resource holder template class idea. It just makes things a bit cleaner and though I'll still have to make sure my subclass is getting the right kind of resource, it will feel cleaner. Thanks very much!